# Two smart contracts interact can't pass value when I using web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, blockchain, remix

I have two different smart contracts **interaction_1** and **interaction_2**

I input the data(team) from remix ide.

What I want to accomplish is when user input team in  user_input function at interaction_1, teamAcceptedEvent.watch in interaction_test.js will start working, and then to put interaction_1 contract address into interaction_2 getValue function, and  interaction_2 contract will receive the user input from interaction_1.

It works fine when I tested it in remix, but when I use web3.js to do it, everything goes smoothly, but interaction_2 didn't get the data from interaction_1.

I'm not sure is there any problem with sendTransaction or the gas price?
I'm just trying to test two smart contract interact using web3.js. thanks

**interaction_1**

```java
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract interaction_1 {

    string public description;
    string public user_prediction;
    uint public amount;
    event teamAccepted(string team_1);


    function user_input (string memory team) public payable {
           user_prediction = team;
           emit teamAccepted(user_prediction);

    }
    function get_user_input()view public returns(string memory) {
        return user_prediction;
    }

}

contract interaction_2 {
    function getValue (address addr)public returns (string memory);
}
```

**interaction_2**

```java
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract interaction_2{
    string public get_user_prediction;
    function getValue (address addr)public returns (string memory){ 
        interaction_1 b = interaction_1(addr);
        return get_user_prediction = b.get_user_input();
    }
}
contract interaction_1 {
    function user_input (string memory team_1)public payable;
    function get_user_input()public returns(string memory);
}
```

**interaction_test.js**

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var abi_1=[...];

var abi_2=[...];

var contractAddress_1 = "0xa4349e4081b28acb426a3332a17a7333bcf3e640";
var contractAddress_2 = "0x0d2c978af4fdeec4070a6147a352235d0c01ca26";
var interaction_1 = web3.eth.contract(abi_1).at(contractAddress_1);
var interaction_2 = web3.eth.contract(abi_2).at(contractAddress_2);

var teamAcceptedEvent = interaction_1.teamAccepted();

teamAcceptedEvent.watch(function(error, result){
            if (!error)
                { 
                    if(result.args.team_1 != null && result.args.team_1 != '')
                    {
                        console.log("get user input");
                        interaction_2.getValue.sendTransaction("0xa4349e4081b28acb426a3332a17a7333bcf3e640",{
                            from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
                            gas:2000000},function (error, result){ 
                            if(!error){
                                console.log(result);
                            } else{
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });                 
                }  
                } else {      
                    console.log(error);
                }
        });
```

Comment: What is your Web3 version?

Comment: You have here two different contracts named `interaction_1` and two different contracts named `interaction_2`. Please clear that up!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get return value from a solidity function, you need to define it as **view** function, though you can still retrieve value by making change in your javascript part using

```
interaction_2.getValue.call()
```

instead of

```
interaction_2.getValue.sendTransaction()
```

In this way, you can call the function and retrieve the return value without making any change in the state.

In solidity, **view** function does not change any state and accesses state and returns value if defined to do so.

So you can define the function **getValue** in **interaction_2** like below

```
function getValue (address addr)public view returns (string memory)
```

instead of

```
function getValue (address addr)public  returns (string memory)
```

Besides, in javascript part, when calling method **getValue**, you need to use

```
interaction_2.getValue.call()
```

instead of

```
interaction_2.getValue.sendTransaction()
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried to define it as view function, but it got an error, it shows this expression modifies the state. because what I want is interaction_2  to receive the data from interaction_1, then interaction_2 will modifies the states(get_user_prediction inside get_user_prediction state's will make the change).

Comment: Then, do no change to getValue() function. To get the address you want, you need to call interaction_2.getValue.call(). After make the transaction using interaction_2.getValue.sendTransaction()